# Why is the equation of the induced current in the secondary coil in a transformer true?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

According to introductory physics books, the induced voltage in the primary coil due to self-inductance = the emf of the voltage source= N1*(change in magnetic flux/time). I find this statement wrong because if the net voltage in the primary loop is zero. Then, the the emf of the DC source = - (the induced emf due to both self-induction  and mutual induction). "Assume that our ideal transformer has no loss of electric energy, so P1 = P2,
or (V1)rms(I1)rms = (V2)rms(I2)rms." Why is this statement true? According to the book the induced emf in the primary coil is due to self-inductance. According to me: the energy loss due to self-induction is not related to the energy in the second coil. Because the energy loss due to self induction must be conserved in the magnetic field. It will be consumed when we suddenly open the circuit of the primary coil. Also, the power in the secondary coil = the induced power in the primary coil due to mutual induction, not self-induction.

Comment: Please respect your readers. Break text into paragraphs, use diagrams with labels, and use LaTeX for equations. This is very hard to read right now

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal transformer in which no current is being drawn from the secondary, the current in the primary is determined by the inductive reactance of the primary and is out of phase with the voltage, thus drawing no power.  The voltage in each coil is determined by the rate of change of the flux. If the input voltage is fixed, then the magnitude of the flux is fixed. If current flows in the secondary, its field causes a phase change in the flux. That causes the current in the primary to shift toward being in phase with the voltage.  The input power must match the output power. Both can be dependent on the phase difference between current and voltage. There is no power lost to inductance, but any resistance in the coils will dissipate power and complicate the situation.